# How to remove a workstation from a domain with no DC

Tags: windows-vista, active-directory, domain-controller

My Google-fu is failing me for me some reason but I need to remove a machine (Vista workstation) from a non-existent domain and domain controller.  It's prompting me for the domain administrator's username and password, which I do not have (nor would it help, I'm assuming).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just hit cancel when it prompts you; it will bypass disabling/deleting the AD account and join the workgroup.